# css doesn't apply on default selected nav-link in vue 3 project with bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-5, nav

my first time, be patient pls.

I want to highlight the selected nav-link, it works well but the first one (small), doesn't highlight.

Even when i select the other ones, (medium or large, that do change the color), and select the first one (small) again, small won't change its color.

and its also just black at the beginning.

here my code , I am using vue and bootstrap is installed

```
<template>
  <div >
    <nav>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <button
          class="nav-link car-head active"
          id="nav-ssprinter-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-ssprinter"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-ssprinter"
          aria-selected="true"
        >Small
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link car-head"
          id="nav-msprinter-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-msprinter"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-msprinter"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Middle
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link car-head"
          id="nav-xlsprinter-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-xlsprinter"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-xlsprinter"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          big
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="nav-ssprinter"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-ssprinter-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
Small text
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-msprinter"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-msprinter-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
      medium text
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-xlsprinter"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-xlsprinter-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
      big text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>




<script>

export default {
  components: {},
  methods: {},

};
</script>

<style>
.car-head{
color: black !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
}
 .car-head + .active {
  color: rgb(243, 158, 0) !important;
  background: rgb(220, 220, 220) !important;

}
</style>
```

i have checked the id's and classes and changed the order in the css part at the bottom,
it helped at a different problem don't didn't solved this one.

i hoped to find a mistyping in class names for the small nav-link, because, I see no other reason that it's color is always black, at the beginning (default selected) and when I select It after selecting something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `+` selector, which means: select the adjacent next sibling. So this will only work in certain scenarios.

In your example I suppose you want style the `car-head` class when it has the `active` class. In that case you will need to use this selector combination: `.car-head.active`

Read up on CSS selectors here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Or in a great video explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1mER1bV0N0

```css
.car-head {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.car-head.active {
  color: rgb(243, 158, 0) !important;
  background: rgb(220, 220, 220) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link car-head active" id="nav-ssprinter-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-ssprinter" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ssprinter" aria-selected="true">Small
        </button>
      <button class="nav-link car-head" id="nav-msprinter-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-msprinter" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-msprinter" aria-selected="false">
          Middle
        </button>
      <button class="nav-link car-head" id="nav-xlsprinter-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-xlsprinter" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-xlsprinter" aria-selected="false">
          big
        </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-ssprinter" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ssprinter-tab" tabindex="0">
      Small text
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-msprinter" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-msprinter-tab" tabindex="0">
      medium text
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-xlsprinter" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-xlsprinter-tab" tabindex="0">
      big text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **anchor tag** and **:visited** instead of button

```
example :

   

.car-head:visited{
   background-color : blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if you check the code, you see that I already did that.

Comment: i think use anchor tag and :visited instead of button